# Angular 2 - Image upload , File not getting uploaded to backend (no error listed)

Tags: angular, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an image in angular 2 , i have no error listed but there is no change in the position the file added detailed code is given below

```
**.ts**
............
  onFileChange(event) {
    if(event.target.files.length > 0) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      this.fileName = file.name;
      this.imageUpload['upload'] = this.fileName;
      this.form.get('upload').setValue(file);
      console.log(file);
      console.log('filename',this.fileName);


    }
  }

 private prepareSave(): any {
    let inputVal = new FormData();
    inputVal.append('upload', this.form.get('upload').value,this.imageUpload['upload']);
    console.log(inputVal);
    return inputVal;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.imageUpload['upload'] = this.fileName;
    const formModel = this.prepareSave();
    this.loading = true;

    var body = formModel;
    let url = this.ImageUploadURL;
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' ,'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.accountsService.accessToken });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    console.log(options);
    console.log(body);
    console.log(url);
    // In a real-world app you'd have a http request / service call here like
     return this.http.post(url, body, options)
          .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
          .subscribe(
              data => console.log('success'),
              error => console.log(error)

        )
  }
...............
```

in console its getting success[image]

the method is post with url and 
**{
upload:""
}**

In the network im getting[image]

what might be the error that there is no change on desired portion?

is there any other way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Angular, when using multipart form-data and you are using FormData object, you MUST NOT specifiy the Content-Type header.

By doing so you are preventing the http stack to set it to the proper value which [MUST include the boundary value](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183).

Just remove the content type header and let the formatter handle that for you, and you should be fine.

Comment: Just arrived at that. the long way around. If my memory serves, this technique didn't work with very early versions of A2. But OP has it working.

Comment: FormData (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FormData) is not coming from Angular it was already like that with Angular 1.5. What might have happened is that some buggy version could have added a header nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

The form encoding needs to be `multipart/form-data` rather than `form-data`.

Try this change:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer' + blah);
```

There is a slightly different approach if you want to refactor your component:

https://gist.github.com/arciisine/ee57727e56cbc5e83739b2c24fd69658

Comment: 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' is given in headers,  is it to be mention somewhere else?

Comment: I'm looking at the _**In the network I'm getting**_ image you shared above. Clearly, `form-data` is being sent as the enctype. So, to me, it doesn't seem it is being set in the header (or being re-set along the way).

Comment: I do see the header being set. Don't know why the image shows different enctype.

Comment: Try this: on the form element itself, place the enctype attribute like so: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ...>`

Comment: Hi, Still No change

Comment: This is why there were no many npm "file upload" packages for Angular 2.  Try using `headers.set()` rather than passing them into the constructor. See revised answer.

Comment: Got an **error** http://192.168.2.23:8888/zaska-web/public/api/v2/imagegallery/shop/155/imagType/1 401 (Unauthorized)

Response {_body: "{"error":"Unauthenticated."}", status: 401, ok: false, statusText: "Unauthorized", headers: Headers, …}

Comment: Well, progress: you did do this right? `'Bearer ' + this.accountsService.accessToken`

Comment: let headers = new Headers();
headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer' + this.accountsService.accessToken);

yes given like this

Comment: are you sure you don't have any interceptors or guards between this request and the server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167451/discussion-between-aashiq-rathnadas-and-randy-casburn).

Comment: Ah - you missed the space after the work 'Bearer '<---- here